# Javascript: add iframe element after page has loaded

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript I need to find the best way to add a iframe element that is:

1. Completely hidden from the user.
2. Created after the page has fully loaded. i.e. Should be completely unobtrusive to the user and not affect loading of images and other scripts etc, in any way.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can add a hidden `iframe` like this:

```
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = /* your URL here */;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

If you need to do that on page load, you can:

- Use `type="module"` on your `script` tag to make it a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (in environments that support modules; basically everywhere now). Modules are really useful for encapsulation, and also get deferred (not executed until the HTML is fully parsed and the DOM populated with the results). Using `type="module"` defers execution even with inline scripts. Example:

  ```html
  <script type="module">
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.style.display = "none";
  iframe.src = /* your URL here */;
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  </script>
  ```
- Use [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) on your `script` tag (in environments that don't yet support modules). `defer` scripts don't run until the HTML is parsed and the DOM populated with the results. Unfortunately, though, `defer` only works with `src` scripts, not inline scripts. So you could put the code above in a `.js` file and use:

  ```html
  <script defer src="./yourfile.js"></script>
  ```
- Put your `script` at the very end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` element (in environments that don't support `type="module"` or `defer`, but there basically aren't any left, even IE11 supported `defer`).

  ```html
  <script>
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.style.display = "none";
  iframe.src = /* your URL here */;
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  </script>
  </body><!-- <========= Notice this is at the end of the body tag -->
  ```
- Hook it up via the `window` `load` event, but I don't recommend it; the `window` `load` event happens quite late in the page load process (waiting for all images to load, for instance).

  ```html
  <!-- NOT RECOMMENDED -->
  <script>
  window.addEventListener(function() {
       const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
       iframe.style.display = "none";
       iframe.src = /* your URL here */;
       document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  });
  </script>
  ```

Comment: I need to do it "after" page load... and I don't want the rendering of the iframe contents to in any-way affect the loading of the website.

Comment: @EddyR: That's why you put the script tag at the very end of the document. But if you want to be sure to stay completely out of the way of image loading, do it in `window.onload`. That event happens after *everything* else is done loading, including all images. I've updated with an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to load multiple iFrames after your page has loaded you can also combine it with a `setTimeout()`, `.ready()` and `.each()` function:

Markup:

```
<span class="hidden iframe-holder" data-iframe="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/6Js1lHzz7gu7XTyvcdLuPa"></span>
<iframe  src=""></iframe>

<span class="hidden iframe-holder" data-iframe="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/4icHXsDdv3eHfa7g3WQWAP"></span>
<iframe  src=""></iframe>

<span class="hidden iframe-holder" data-iframe="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/3BukJHUieqwat6hwALC23w"></span>
<iframe src=""></iframe>

<span class="hidden iframe-holder" data-iframe="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/1Pkj7fCqzg4o6ivPuWU0vB"></span>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

JS (in this case jQuery - sorry I'm from the WordPress cosmos):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  setTimeout(function(){  
    $(".iframe-holder").each(function(){
      var iframesrces = $(this).attr('data-iframe');
      var nextiFrame = $(this).next();
      $(nextiFrame).attr('src',iframesrces);            
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

This solution is useful if you get your strings dynamically from a database. Just make sure that you place the iframe source holder span "before" your iframe in the DOM and it will attach its `data-iframe` attribute to the iFrame element after your page has been loaded.

Comment: You should not have empty `src` attribute, use `src='about:blank'`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946607/is-an-empty-iframe-src-valid)