# Reload maps iframe on press a button

Tags: ajax, google-maps, iframe

I have the problem, that not everybody who's visiting my website won't be tracked by google. 
But in my county the law says, that you must have an imprint, and that have to be clear and easely to understand. So the most sites uses additional an google maps iframe. But when using this, google is crawling which is against the upcomming privacy law. So I'm searching a way, to make a button, which reloads the google iframe, when clicked, but not before. I think that must be done with AJAX, or is there an other possibility?

As a background Info, I wasn't succesfull with modificate some AJAX templates, so yes, need help.

Greetz QuackBrick

Comment: The problem definition just confuses this issue. Is it as simple as "When a button is clicked, show an iFrame?" [This answer shows you how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069915/javascript-add-iframe-element-after-page-has-loaded) to add an iframe to a page on click - note that as long as you set the URL on click, nothing will be loaded until then.

Comment: Hy, thx for your answer. But the important thing is, that the iframe isn't just hidden, he should be only shown (an work/collect datas), when someone has accepted that, by clicking on the button. The solution you linked - after a first, fast view - looks like it only does change the visibility, but then, I think so, the google service is collecting datas already, even when the viewer hadn't clicked on the button. Or are I'm missunderstanding the others solution?

Comment: The URL is not loaded until it is set by the line `iframe.src = url` when the user clicks accept. So data will only be sent to Google *after* they click your Accept button.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, missunderstuud this point.

Comment: (You can test this by keeping an eye on the Developer Console as you load the page and click on various buttons - you'll see whatever HTTP calls it makes :)

Comment: I wanted to combine that with this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp but wasn't succesfull on this way. I changed [ window.onload = function() ] to [ object.onclick = function() ]